# Perl CGI::Session return empty

Tags: perl, session

I am trying to create a new session with the CGI::Session module.

```
$session = new CGI::Session("driver:file", undef, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
$sid = $session->id;
```

But it returns
[error] Can't call method "id" on an undefined value at /home/httpd/cgi-bin/login.cgi line 74,  line 36.,

It seems that the new session returns null. It doesn't seem to create any new files in the tmp folder, too.
What could be the problem? Maybe the library is not installed correctly?

Comment: Have you double checked that the user that Perl CGI runs as can write to /tmp? (I'd expect anyone can write to /tmp but just in case....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract from the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aSession#new-):

> new()
>
> Returns new session object, or undef on failure. Error
>   message is accessible through errstr() - class method.

So you might want to check for something like this:

```
my $session = CGI::Session->new or die CGI::Session->errstr;
```

Comment: It seems that it was a missing module :)